# Using bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-combined.min.css causes UI issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use the following two CSS files, my UI is getting an unexpected view. Specially, the modal popup UI changes a lot. Any idea why?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

Comment: be specific to your problem.. what is not working?

Comment: I have made some improvements to your post. Using appropriate grammar is helpful to getting good answers on SO. That said, even with the minor improvements, you have not included enough information in your question for it to be answerable in your current form. Please include some additional clarifications about what your problem is and how it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using different versions of bootstrap (v2 and v3). They probably override or interfere with each other. You should use only the latest version (not the combined one). From what I know, bootstrap v3 has responsive design included.

From bootstrap:

> Bootstrap 3 is not backwards compatible with v2.x.

Taken from [joshunts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180360/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrap-css-and-bootstrap-combined-min-css):

> The file bootstrap-combined.min.css is for Bootstrap v2, it is the
>   combined css file of bootstrap.css (the main css file) and
>   bootstrap-responsive.css (the responsive Bootstrap styles). It's
>   exactly the same as using those two files separately but it just saves
>   you an extra request.
>
> Conclusion
>
> bootstrap.min.css = compressed version of bootstrap.css
>   bootstrap-combined.min.css = bootstrap.min.css +
>   bootstrap-responsive.min.css

Comment: Can you share latest version of bootstrap-combined.min.css? (3.x.x)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Bootstrap 3 has responsive design included. Don't think you need the combined version. I would also recommend you adding a screenshot of the issue or a sample code in jsfiddle next time. Will be much easier to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I was required combined version for pagination